# How to execute and display output from command cgi script

Tags: html, bash, cgi

I want to execute command from variable and display the output.
code look like this but it doesn't work I don't know exactly why?

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo

argu="arp -a | grep $REMOTE_ADDR | awk '{print $4}'"

echo '<html> <head> <title> CGI script </title> </head> <body>'
echo "<h1>HELLO $REMOTE_ADDR</h1>"
echo "Mac is ${argu}"
```

Comment: You should include the output you get, and show what part is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has a few issues, mainly the `argu` command should run in a sub-shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo

argu="$(arp -a | grep "$REMOTE_ADDR" | awk '{print $4}')"

echo '<html> <head> <title> CGI script </title> </head> <body>'
echo "<h1>HELLO $REMOTE_ADDR</h1>"
echo "Mac is $argu"
```

In addition, the variable you `grep` should be double-quoted. You can always check the syntax of scripts such as this @ shellcheck.net.

Comment: It still doesn't work sir. Can't get the mac address

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you set `argu` like this:

```
argu=`arp -a | grep "$REMOTE_ADDR" | awk '{print $4}'`
```

The reasons:

- Command substitution can be done with `command`
- `$4` must not be enclosed by double quotation marks, otherwise it will be substituted by the shell instead of awk.

Make sure `$REMOTE_ADDR` is set.